# Neural Network, Getting output less then 1

Tags: c#, neural-network

I am trying to create a neural network for the function `y=e^(-(x-u)^2)/(2*o^2))` where `u = 50` and `o = 15`.

I must train my neural network so I can find the 2 x's for each y. I have created the folling code, it seems to learn it nicely, but once I test the outputs go I only get numbers around 0.99 to 1 where I should get 25 and 75 and I just can't see why. My best guess is that my error correction is wrong, but can't find the error. The neural network uses back-propagation.

The test code and training set

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            args = new string[] {
                "c:\\testTrain.csv",
                "c:\\testValues.csv"
            };

            // Output File
            string fileTrainPath = null;
            string fileValuesPath = null;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                fileTrainPath = args[0];
                if (File.Exists(fileTrainPath))
                    File.Delete(fileTrainPath);
                fileValuesPath = args[1];
                if (File.Exists(fileValuesPath))
                    File.Delete(fileValuesPath);
            }

            double learningRate = 0.1;
            double u = 50;
            double o = 15;

            Random rand = new Random();

            Network net = new Network(1, 8, 4, 2);
            NetworkTrainer netTrainer = new NetworkTrainer(learningRate, net);

            List<TrainerSet> TrainerSets = new List<TrainerSet>(); 
            for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                double random = rand.NextDouble();

                TrainerSets.Add(new TrainerSet(){
                    Inputs = new double[] { random },
                    Outputs = getX(random, u, o)
                });
            }

            // Train Network
            string fileTrainValue = String.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                if (i == 5000)
                { }
                double error = netTrainer.RunEpoch(TrainerSets);
                Console.WriteLine("Epoch " + i + ": Error = " + error);
                if(fileTrainPath != null)
                    fileTrainValue += i + "," + learningRate + "," + error + "\n";
            }
            if (fileTrainPath != null)
                File.WriteAllText(fileTrainPath, fileTrainValue);

            // Test Network
            string fileValuesValue = String.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                double y = rand.NextDouble();
                double[] dOutput = getX(y, u, o);
                double[] Output = net.Compute(new double[] { y });

                if (fileValuesPath != null)
                    fileValuesValue += i + "," + y + "," + dOutput[0] + "," + dOutput[1] + "," + Output[0] + "," + Output[1] + "\n";
            }
            if (fileValuesPath != null)
                File.WriteAllText(fileValuesPath, fileValuesValue);
        }

        public static double getResult(int x, double u, double o)
        {
            return Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x-u,2)/(2*Math.Pow(o,2)));
        }

        public static double[] getX(double y, double u, double o)
        {
            return new double[] {
                u + Math.Sqrt(2 * Math.Pow(o, 2) * Math.Log(1/y)),
                u - Math.Sqrt(2 * Math.Pow(o, 2) * Math.Log(1/y)),
            };
        }
    }
```

The code behind the network

```
public class Network
{
    protected int inputsCount;
    protected int layersCount;
    protected NetworkLayer[] layers;
    protected double[] output;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return layers.Count();
        }
    }
    public NetworkLayer this[int index]
    {
        get { return layers[index]; }
    }

    public Network(int inputsCount, params int[] neuronsCount)
    {
        this.inputsCount = Math.Max(1, inputsCount);
        this.layersCount = Math.Max(1, neuronsCount.Length);

        layers = new NetworkLayer[neuronsCount.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < layersCount; i++)
            layers[i] = new NetworkLayer(neuronsCount[i],
                (i == 0) ? inputsCount : neuronsCount[i - 1]);
    }

    public virtual double[] Compute(double[] input)
    {
        output = input;

        foreach (NetworkLayer layer in layers)
            output = layer.Compute(output);

        return output;
    }
}
public class NetworkLayer
{
    protected int inputsCount = 0;
    protected int neuronsCount = 0;
    protected Neuron[] neurons;
    protected double[] output;

    public Neuron this[int index]
    {
        get { return neurons[index]; }
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get { return neurons.Length; }
    }
    public int Inputs
    {
        get { return inputsCount; }
    }
    public double[] Output
    {
        get { return output; }
    }

    public NetworkLayer(int neuronsCount, int inputsCount)
    {
        this.inputsCount    = Math.Max( 1, inputsCount );
        this.neuronsCount   = Math.Max( 1, neuronsCount );

        neurons = new Neuron[this.neuronsCount];
        output = new double[this.neuronsCount];

        // create each neuron
        for (int i = 0; i < neuronsCount; i++)
            neurons[i] = new Neuron(inputsCount);
    }

    public virtual double[] Compute(double[] input)
    {
        // compute each neuron
        for (int i = 0; i < neuronsCount; i++)
            output[i] = neurons[i].Compute(input);

        return output;
    }
}
public class Neuron
{
    protected static Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    public int Inputs;
    public double[] Input;
    public double[] Weights;
    public double Output = 0;
    public double Threshold;
    public double Error;

    public Neuron(int inputs)
    {
        this.Inputs = inputs;
        Weights = new double[inputs];

        for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++)
            Weights[i] = rand.NextDouble() * 0.5;
    }

    public double Compute(double[] inputs)
    {
        Input = inputs;

        double e = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
            e += Weights[i] * inputs[i];

        e -= Threshold;
        return (Output = sigmoid(e));
    }

    private double sigmoid(double value)
    {
        return (1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-1 * value)));
        //return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-value));
    }
}
```

My Trainer

```
public class NetworkTrainer
{
    private Network network;
    private double learningRate = 0.1;

    public NetworkTrainer(double a, Network network)
    {
        this.network = network;
        this.learningRate = a;
    }

    public double Run(double[] input, double[] output)
    {
        network.Compute(input);

        return CorrectErrors(output);
    }

    public double RunEpoch(List<TrainerSet> sets)
    {
        double error = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0, n = sets.Count; i < n; i++)
            error += Run(sets[i].Inputs, sets[i].Outputs);

        // return summary error
        return error;
    }

    private double CorrectErrors(double[] desiredOutput)
    {
        double[] errorLast = new double[desiredOutput.Length];

        NetworkLayer lastLayer = network[network.Count - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < desiredOutput.Length; i++)
        {
            // S(p)=y(p)*[1-y(p)]*(yd(p)-y(p))
            lastLayer[i].Error = lastLayer[i].Output * (1-lastLayer[i].Output)*(desiredOutput[i] - lastLayer[i].Output);
            errorLast[i] = lastLayer[i].Error;
        }

        // Calculate errors
        for (int l = network.Count - 2; l >= 0; l--)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < network[l].Count; n++)
            {
                double newError = 0;
                for (int np = 0; np < network[l + 1].Count; np++)
                {
                    newError += network[l + 1][np].Weights[n] * network[l + 1][np].Error;
                }
                network[l][n].Error = newError;
            }
        }

        // Update Weights
        // w = w + (a * input * error)
        for (int l = network.Count - 1; l >= 0; l--)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < network[l].Count; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < network[l][n].Inputs; i++)
                {
                    // deltaW = a * y(p) * s(p)
                    double deltaW = learningRate * network[l][n].Output * network[l][n].Error;
                    network[l][n].Weights[i] += deltaW;
                }

            }
        }

        double returnError = 0;
        foreach (double e in errorLast)
            returnError += e;
        return returnError;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific issue you're having? This is quite lengthy code.. http://sscce.org/

Comment: As i said, i am only getting outputs of 0.99 to 1 where it should be eks. 75 or 25, i don't know what but i must have implemented something wrong.

Comment: i have been told that it is because my activation function gives a value between 0 and 1, and that i need to scale it. But i can not find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regression problems your output layer should have the identity (or at least a linear) activation function. This way you don't have to scale your output. The derivative of the identity function is 1 and thus the derivative dE/da_i for the output layer is y-t (`lastLayer[i].Output - desiredOutput[i]`).